# Definition of these metrics recorded in /proc/vmstat on RHEL 5.3 (paging/swapping?)

Tags: redhat, vmware-esx, virtual-memory

This question relates to the definition of specific metrics recorded in /proc/vmstat on RHEL 5.3.

I'm using nmon to monitor a load test which consists of simulating 2500 users carrying out a days workload in one hour. Recently, I've seen bad performance and am in the process of diagnosing and excluding various considerations.

We are running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga) on vmware ESX. The physical server I'm focussing on runs and Oracle Application Server (this comprises and Apache HTTP server and OC4J J2EE container).

The nmon charts I am viewing are showing consistent allocation to the pswpin metric. Summarised as; min = 4312; max = 245352; avg = 86734. Nmon shows these values measured in "kBytes per second"

The following metrics are zero throughout the test;

- pswpout
- pgpgin
- pgpgout

I'm confused as to what this combination of metrics means, given my understanding of paging and swapping.

**My Question(s):**

1. Can someone please confirm what these metrics represent?
2. Any idea what system behaviour might cause this type of VM behaviour?

At the moment I'm trying to exclude virtual memory issues as a cause of poor performance.

**EDIT:** I have found evidence of a large number of fork() calls throughout the test. I suspect the Apache daemons. But could process creation be the cause of these metrics?

**EDIT:** I've added a typical sample of the VM output from nmon. Apologies for the poor formatting.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

```
T0001   -1  22  -1  -1  -1  150 -1  -1  -1  5196046163  -1  0   30  100199751   3060    -1  0   -1  885 -1  -1  -1  46163   -1  -1  18  -1  828189171   -1  -1  3838    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  165231  
03:07:23    Paging and Virtual Memory   nr_dirty    nr_writeback    nr_unstable nr_page_table_pages nr_mapped   nr_slab pgpgin  pgpgout pswpin  pswpout pgfree  pgactivate  pgdeactivate    pgfault pgmajfault  pginodesteal    slabs_scanned   kswapd_steal    kswapd_inodesteal   pageoutrun  allocstall  pgrotated   pgalloc_high    pgalloc_normal  pgalloc_dma pgrefill_high   pgrefill_normal pgrefill_dma    pgsteal_high    pgsteal_normal  pgsteal_dma pgscan_kswapd_high  pgscan_kswapd_normal    pgscan_kswapd_dma   pgscan_direct_high  pgscan_direct_normal    pgscan_direct_dma
03:07:33    -1  99  -1  -1  -1  241 0   0   0   77526   0   0   0   824 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   77526   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   78216   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:07:43    -1  10  -1  -1  -1  262 0   0   0   21653   0   0   8   500 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   21653   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17675   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:07:53    -1  69  -1  -1  -1  257 0   0   0   115744  0   0   0   724 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   115744  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -79544  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:03    -1  69  -1  -1  -1  196 0   0   0   81202   0   0   0   628 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   81202   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -18335  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:13    -1  81  -1  -1  -1  205 0   0   0   29051   0   0   0   352 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   29051   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   24449   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:24    -1  91  -1  -1  -1  131 0   0   0   122795  0   0   0   1172    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   122795  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9640    0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:34    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  182 0   0   0   74914   0   0   4   372 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   74914   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -24477  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:44    -1  38  -1  -1  -1  200 0   0   0   42957   0   0   4   464 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   42957   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   42778   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:08:54    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  141 0   0   0   89751   0   0   36  1000    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   89751   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -9665   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:04    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  171 0   0   0   74740   0   0   4   516 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   74740   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -24583  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:14    -1  10  -1  -1  -1  179 0   0   0   56063   0   0   0   500 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   56063   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   56384   0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:24    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  74  0   0   0   75623   0   0   0   696 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   75623   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -23994  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:34    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  137 0   0   0   75466   0   0   8   972 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   75466   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -23837  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:44    -1  3   -1  -1  -1  153 0   0   0   72535   0   0   4   460 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -927465 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -26880  0   0   0   0   0   0   
03:09:54    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  170 0   0   0   56775   0   0   0   284 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   56775   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   56895   0   0   0   0   0   0
03:10:04    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  166 0   0   0   74756   0   0   0   1116    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   74756   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -24568  0   0   0   0   0   0
03:10:14    -1  6   -1  -1  -1  148 0   0   0   78043   0   0   0   432 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   78043   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -21241  0   0   0   0   0   0
03:10:24    -1  64  -1  -1  -1  189 0   0   0   64057   0   0   0   412 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   64057   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   60788   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Please post entire set of nmon stats, and preferably vmstat's output.

Comment: I'm nervous about posting the full NMON, as there are machine and configuration specifics in the report.

The NMON report is in excel format. I've cut this down to contain the info that has been discussed so far. I can see a means of uploading these results to serverfault. I'm just about to hit the FAQ to see if I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pgpgin      -  Number of kilobytes the system has paged in from disk per second.
pgpgout     -  Number of kilobytes the system has paged out to disk per second.
pswpin      -  Number of kilobytes the system has swapped in from disk per second.
pswpout     -  Number of kilobytes the system has swapped out to disk per second.
```

I am 87% sure, that each page that increased pswpin counter should also increase pgpgin. You say it isn't . Hmmm.

<strike>This may be too simplistic thing to check (sorry!) but... Are you 200% sure, that the metric you observe is pswpin, not pgpgin? The later would translate to: process is reading some files.</strike>

Other explanation is that application has been heavily swapped out before the test, then the system obtained a lot of free memory. And during the test you are observing as it is "coming back to life" (constantly swapping itself in - as the code execution progresses), without reading/writing any files. But why in such scenario isn't the pgpgin increased along pswpin is beyond my comprehension.

Maybe your charts are tweaked, so pswpin is substracted from pgpgin? One point to back this up is that both metrics are typically in pages (in /proc/vmstat), and you have them converted to KB/s.

EDIT: This might be ESX-related. My wild guess that it is a side effect of either balooning or transparent page sharing (TPS). Are you able to [analyze via esxtop on the ESX](http://www.van-lieshout.com/2009/05/esx-memory-management-%E2%80%93-part-3/)? Here is [another esxtop guide](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-9279).

EDIT: Your nmon stats seem broken. First of all, there are more column names than actual metrics (i.e. you don't have data for last column `pgscan_direct_dma`). There are a lot -1 or 0 values on metrics that should be there on a busy system, not only pgpgin is missing. Pgsteal and pgrotated are there, but sometimes negative, which is not possible.

So, look at /proc/vmstat, what's going on there? And use other tools to confirm nmon stats.

Comment: - The counters are as I describe (no direct relationship between pswpin and pgpgin )

 - Nmon presents the metric as pswpin. I've no reason (yet) to doubt that this is correct. But if there is supporting evidence then I'll consider corroborating the figures with another tool 

- I've found that there are significant fork() calls throughout the test (up to 80 per second ). Could this Virtual Memory behaviour just be related to new process creation?

 - Nmon doco states this data is a direct copy of /proc/vmstat. Do you have anything that supports the assertion that this is measured in pages?

Comment: I have no evidence that this relates to the baloon process. We have had issues heer and have been monitoring vmmemctl. I don't know about TPS - I'll have to read some more.

We have no access to the ESX layer (the SX environment is supplied and controlled by a company internal service and they don't provide any monitoring privileges.)

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your edits on question.

Comment: OK - I'll confirm vmstat behaviour. I've also found the nmon source so may have a peek to understand what it does here. I'll post back...Cheers.

Comment: This issue is still ongoing - currently being hampered by a third party software issue. I still plan toi post back when I can get a clean tests run with raw metrics from /proc/vmstat. This may not be until the New Year though.

Comment: Cool, happy new year then.

Comment: An update, is:

* The nmon stats were broken - I reviewed the code for nmon and things weren't right
* Regardless of the issues with nmon, vmstat showed that lots of forking was taking place as well as vm activity.
* Investigating the forking, all I managed to do was confirm that apache was making regular clone() calls, which are classed under the fork metric.

When we moved to a new environment (still virtualised but fewer VM sharing) we received  performance was satisfactory.

As performance is within requirement on the target hardware, this issue has been parked.